# In mongoDB, how do I get the id of an object created using insertOne() using async / await?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

So I am creating a user object and inserting it into my mongo database using async / await.

Like so:

```
    await db.collection('users').insertOne({
      name: 'testName',
      age: 20
    });
    console.log('new user created');
```

I would like to get the Id from the object I have just added. I am currently doing this like so:

```
    const newUser = await db.collection('users').insertOne({
      name: 'testName',
      age: 20
    });
    console.log('new user created');
    console.log(newUser.ops[0]._id);
```

This works as I would like it to but it doesn't seem like the cleanest way to do this. Is there a better way to get the newly created object's id using async / await?

Comment: What makes you think this isn't "clean"? What does any of this have to do with `async`/`await`? These are just promise revolvers when it comes down to it. It's really not clear what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:

> insertOne Returns:    A document containing:
>   A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was disabled.
>   A field insertedId with the _id value of the inserted document.

Example:

```
{
   "acknowledged" : true,
   "insertedId" : ObjectId("56fc40f9d735c28df206d078")
}
```

[Documentation HERE](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/)